# How to access response value out of OnResponse method?

Tags: java, android

I want to see my array list in my logcat but when I run my app in logcat it shows that size of my array list is zero and there is no elements in it

this is my activity

```
   public class Tmp2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        public RequestQueue queue;
        static ArrayList<Question> array_list;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmp2);
            array_list = new ArrayList<>();
            queue= AppController.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json",
                    (JSONArray) null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                                try {
                                    Question question = new Question();
                                    question.setAnswer(response.getJSONArray(i).get(0).toString());
                                    question.setAnswertrue((Boolean) response.getJSONArray(i).get(1));
                                    array_list.add(question);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }Log.d("wakwash","array "+array_list.size());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            Log.d("json","array "+array_list.size());
            queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
            Log.d("json","array "+array_list);
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
2020-10-25 00:32:43.548 18576-18576/com.example.practice D/json: array 0
2020-10-25 00:32:43.548 18576-18576/com.example.practice D/json: array []
```

its showing that size of my array is zero and there is no element it but when i use this log in onResonse it gives sizeand elements both. How can I access my array list out of the response

Comment: **Please don't abuse bold. It makes your post harder to read**

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are logging your array size at wrong place even before you're getting the response, you are making a call which is asynchronous but the log that you've written is executed in synchronous manner that will always be empty.
Log your data when your response is received i.e in **onResponse** callback.

```
public class Tmp2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        public RequestQueue queue;
        static ArrayList<Question> array_list;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmp2);
            array_list = new ArrayList<>();
            queue= AppController.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json",
                    (JSONArray) null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                                try {
                                    Question question = new Question();
                                    question.setAnswer(response.getJSONArray(i).get(0).toString());
                                    question.setAnswertrue((Boolean) response.getJSONArray(i).get(1));
                                    array_list.add(question);
                                    
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }Log.d("wakwash","array "+array_list.size());
                             // Log it over here
                             Log.d("json","array "+array_list.size());                     
                             Log.d("json","array "+array_list);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            //Log removed from here
            queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    }
```

You have to do your work after the response is received rather than doing it outside of the response scope, You can also make a callback for your response.